# Magento custom URL Rewrite not working

Tags: url, pdf, url-rewriting, url-routing, magento-1.5

On my website there is a collection of pdf files for manuals, brochures, MSDS etc.  The links to download these files are scattered across a "downloads" area, informational pages and product page.  We update the brochures on a regular basis so in order to not have to update every single page where the file is linked from I need to know how to create a redirect where the old URL:

http://easypropondproducts.com/media/pdfs/EcoPondKitsBroch-MPF-109.pdf

will permanently redirect to the new URL

http://easypropondproducts.com/media/pdfs/EcoPondKitsBroch-MPF-512.pdf

I have tried custom URL rewrites and it doesn't seem to work how I have configured it:
Type:            custom
ID Path:         /media/pdfs/EcoPondKitsBroch-MPF-109.pdf
Request Path:    /media/pdfs/EcoPondKitsBroch-MPF-109.pdf
Target Path:     http://easypropondproducts.com/media/pdfs/EcoPondKitsBroch-MPF-512.pdf
Redirect:        Permanent (301)

What am I doing wrong? Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot rewrite files in the `media` folder by using Magentos internal URL Rewrite Management.

That's because URLs pointing to Magentos `media` (or `skin` or `js`) folder don't even reach the central entry point at `index.php`, but are served *directly*.

Take a look at Magentos root `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

With your URL, the first `RewriteCond` is the one that doesn't match. This condition says "if the URL does NOT start with `/media/` or `/skin/` or `/js/`".

But your URL *does* start with `/media/`. Hence it will *not* be rewritten to `index.php` and cannot reach Magentos internal URL Rewrite Management.

To achieve what you want you could insert the following line right before the first `RewriteCond`:

```
Redirect 301 /media/pdfs/EcoPondKitsBroch-MPF-109.pdf /media/pdfs/EcoPondKitsBroch-MPF-512.pdf
```

Comment: Thanks, I was really getting frustrated there, but I understand why that wasn't working now.  I tried your solution in the . htaccess file, however it caused an internal server error, luckily I made a backup of the old .htaccess and was able to get everything back to normal.  What could I have done?

Comment: Using the `Redirect` directive should work as long as `mod_alias` is enabled in your Apache config (which usually always is). I just tested it on several Magento installs running under Ubuntu, RHEL and Windows and inserting the line works as expected on all of them for me. I have no idea why it shouldn't work in your environment, except `mod_alias` is disabled, or you didn't insert the line properly. It may be helpful to show us the `.htaccess` file being used the time the result of requesting the PDF was an internal server error.

Comment: Here is what did work, I'll just post future rewrites under the redirect that's working now, thanks for your help!

## enable rewrites
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
Redirect 301 /media/pdfs/EcoPondKitsBroch-MPF-109.pdf http://easypropondproducts.com/media/pdfs/EcoPondKitsBroch-MPF-512.pdf
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root
    #RewriteBase /magento/
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]